# Exporting pandas dataframe to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm loading a SQL table into a dataframe, and then pushing it directly into a CSV.  The Problem is the export.  I require:

```
value|value|value
```

and I'm getting:

```
"(value|value|value)"
```

How do I get out of that?

Here's my code:

```
for row in self.roster.itertuples():
    SQL = self.GenerateSQL(row)
    self.filename = '{}_{}.csv'.format(row.tablename, now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    # Open the file
    f = open(os.path.join(self.path, self.filename), 'w')
    # Create a connection and get a cursor
    cursor = self.conn.cursor()
    # Execute the query
    cursor.execute(SQL)
    # Get data in batches
    rowcount = 0
    while True:
        # Read the data
        df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchmany(1000))
        # We are done if there are no data
        if len(df) == 0:
            break
        # Let's write to the file
        else:
            rowcount += len(df.index)
            print('Number of rows exported: {}'.format(str(rowcount)))
            df.to_csv(f, header=False, sep='|', index=False)

    # Clean up
    f.close()
    cursor.close()
```

Appreciate any insight.

UPDATE #1
This is an output of the df during the 1000 record cycles.

```
[1000 rows x 1 columns]
Number of rows exported: 10000
                                                     0
0    [11054, Smart Session (30 Minute) , smartsessi...
1    [11055, Best Practices, bestpractices, 2018-06...
2    [11056, Smart Session (30 Minute) , smartsessi...
3    [11057, Best Practices, bestpractices, 2018-06...
```

two records:

```
                                                   0
0  [1, Offrs.com Live Training, livetraining, 201...
1  [2, Offrs.com Live Training, livetraining, 201...
```

Comment: Could you please inspect the `df` variable and see what are the columns? Perhaps it is a tuple you have to unpack before you would be able to construct a dataframe? I am unable to look into what's returned from `cursor.fetchmany(1000)`. I usually avoid use of cursor and just go with a plain SQL query `pd.read_sql_query('select * from climate',con=engine)` with engine coming from `sqlalchemy.create_engine` which supports most of the DBMS servers. Let me know if you would like to have a complete code snippet to be posted.

Comment: One of the reasons why I'm working fetchmany(1000) is to ensure I don't overload the memory on the server. I'm open to recommendations for that as well.

Comment: You can use the `limit` or `top` keyword in the SQL query (depending on what DBMS you are) to limit how many rows you would like to get back, no worries.

Comment: it's not my intent to only pull 1000 records.  It's my intent to pull all records, in chunks.  Most appreciated tho.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you can use `sqlalchemy` package, you would be able to take advantage of the `pd.read_sql` function which handles querying the database and retrieving the data.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432/sample')

df = pd.read_sql_query('select * from climate limit 3',con=engine)
df.to_csv('out.csv', header=False, sep='|', index=False)
```

Alternatively, you can still use the cursor. However, you need to split the rows fetched into individual pieces before constructing a data frame. Currently, the whole row with multiple database table columns is put into a single dataframe row.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  I'm not asking only for 1000 records.  I want all records, but page the output so I don't overload the server.

Comment: What is your DBMS? If it's PostgreSQL, you will be able to use `{'stream_results': True}` when constructing the engine and then use `read_sql_query` with the `chunksize` parameter set https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html

Comment: sql server 2012 unfortunately.  This is the system I have.

Comment: Right. Then let's inspect the `df` variable after you have done `df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchmany(1000))`. Please update the question body with a sample contents of a couple of rows. Perhaps your columns just got stacked into a tuple inside a single df column.

Comment: and example has been pushed to the question area.  Looking forward to your insight.

Comment: As I thought - you need to split your cursor results before creating df - updated my answer. If you could publish a sample of `cursor.fetchmany(2)` I'd be able to say how can this be done.

Comment: Are you sure this is the cursor rows you have published? Looks like pandas rows... I think cursors for MSSQL usually return a list of tuples where each tuple represents a row

Comment: I see where you are getting at.  I can't publish the data itself as it's PII, but the format is as you expected.  fetchmany(1000) and (2) are producing data in this format `[(record),(record)]`

Comment: No problem. When you show `[(record),(record)]`, what is record? You don't have to publish the source data, but you can put dummy values keeping the structure - are you sure it is `[(1,2,3), (4,5,6)]`? Again, you'd need to look into what do you feed to pandas when constructing a df. `pd.DataFrame([(1,2,3), (4,5,6)])` would work nicely, but if you have something nested there, as it looks like that you have, all rows will be put into a single df row.

Comment: so a record does have multiple fields.  in this case `select field1, field2, field3 from table` results in `[(1, 'frank', 'castle'), (2,'casper', 'van diem'), (3, 'john', 'marshall')]`.

Comment: `pd.dataframe([(1, 'frank', 'castle'), (2,'casper', 'van diem'), (3, 'john', 'marshall')])` results in one column of three records.